# Root of AVL tree is receiving garbage instead values in C

Tags: c, data-structures, avl-tree

I basically want to load CSV and insert each record/line in an AVL tree. Here is the code for AVL Tree (you can assume that it's implementation are correct and just copy/paste code this code. If there's any ajustment, please tell me)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_NUMBER 5
#define STRING_MAX 50

typedef struct
{
  int key_idx;
  char column1[STRING_MAX];
  char column2[STRING_MAX];
  char column3[STRING_MAX];
  char column4[STRING_MAX];
  char column5[STRING_MAX];
  char column6[STRING_MAX];
  char column7[STRING_MAX];
  char column8[STRING_MAX];
  char column9[STRING_MAX];
  char column10[STRING_MAX];
} Avl_info;

typedef struct node
{
  Avl_info *avl_info;
  struct node *left, *right;
  int height;
} Node;

// Create a new node
Node *newNode(Avl_info *x)
{
  Node *new = malloc(sizeof(Node));

  if (new)
  {
    new->avl_info = x;
    new->left = NULL;
    new->right = NULL;
    new->height = 0;
  }
  else
  {
    printf("\nERROR to alocate a new node.\n");
  }

  return new;
}

// Max value between 2 values
int max(int a, int b) { return (a > b) ? a : b; }

// Return the node height
int nodeHeight(Node *node)
{
  if (node == NULL)
  {
    return -1;
  }
  else
  {
    return node->height;
  }
}

// Calculate and return a node balancing factor
int balancingFactor(Node *node)
{
  if (node)
  {
    return (nodeHeight(node->left) - nodeHeight(node->right));
  }
  else
  {
    return 0;
  }
}

// ---------------- ROTATIONS ------------------

Node *leftRotation(Node *r)
{
  Node *y, *f;

  y = r->right;
  f = y->left;

  y->left = r;
  r->right = f;

  r->height = max(nodeHeight(r->left), nodeHeight(r->right)) + 1;
  y->height = max(nodeHeight(y->left), nodeHeight(y->right)) + 1;

  return y;
}

Node *rightRotation(Node *r)
{
  Node *y, *f;

  y = r->left;
  f = y->right;

  y->right = r;
  r->left = f;

  r->height = max(nodeHeight(r->left), nodeHeight(r->right)) + 1;
  y->height = max(nodeHeight(y->left), nodeHeight(y->right)) + 1;

  return y;
}

Node *rightLeftRotation(Node *r)
{
  r->right = rightRotation(r->right);
  return leftRotation(r);
}

Node *leftRightRotation(Node *r)
{
  r->left = leftRotation(r->left);
  return rightRotation(r);
}

// Balance the tree, determining the correct rotation given the root
Node *balance(Node *root)
{
  int bf = balancingFactor(root);

  if (bf < -1 && balancingFactor(root->right) <= 0)
    root = leftRotation(root);

  else if (bf > 1 && balancingFactor(root->left) >= 0)
    root = rightRotation(root);

  else if (bf > 1 && balancingFactor(root->left) < 0)
    root = leftRightRotation(root);

  else if (bf < -1 && balancingFactor(root->right) > 0)
    root = rightLeftRotation(root);

  return root;
}

// insert an element in the tree
Node *insert(Node *root, Avl_info *x)
{
  if (root == NULL)
  {
    return newNode(x);
  }
  else
  {
    if (x->key_idx < root->avl_info->key_idx)
    {
      root->left = insert(root->left, x);
    }
    else if (x->key_idx > root->avl_info->key_idx)
      root->right = insert(root->right, x);
    else
      printf("Element %d already exists in the tree.\n", x->key_idx);
  }

  root->height = max(nodeHeight(root->left), nodeHeight(root->right)) + 1;
  root = balance(root);

  return root;
}

// remove an element in the tree
Node *remove_element(Node *root, int key)
{
  if (root == NULL)
  {
    printf("Value not found.");
    return NULL;
  }
  else
  { // search the node to remove
    if (root->avl_info->key_idx == key)
    { // remove leaf nodes
      if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
      {
        free(root);
        printf("Leaf element removed: %d\n", key);
        return NULL;
      }
      else
      { // remove nodes with 2 leafs/son
        if (root->left != NULL && root->right != NULL)
        {
          Node *aux = root->left;
          while (aux->right != NULL)
            aux = aux->right;

          Avl_info *avl_aux;
          avl_aux = root->avl_info;
          root->avl_info = aux->avl_info;
          aux->avl_info = avl_aux;
          printf("Swapped element: %d\n", key);
          root->left = remove_element(root->left, key);
          return root;
        }
        else
        { // remove nodes with 1 leaf/son
          Node *aux;
          if (root->left != NULL)
            aux = root->left;
          else
            aux = root->right;
          free(root);
          printf("Node with 1 leaf removed: %d\n", key);
          return aux;
        }
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if (key < root->avl_info->key_idx)
        root->left = remove_element(root->left, key);
      else
        root->right = remove_element(root->right, key);
    }

    // Recalculate the nodes heights between root and the inserted new node
    root->height = max(nodeHeight(root->left), nodeHeight(root->right)) + 1;

    // balance, if necessary
    root = balance(root);

    return root;
  }
}

void print_table(Avl_info *line)
{
  printf("|%d|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|\n", line->key_idx, line->column1, line->column2, line->column3, line->column4, line->column5, line->column6, line->column7, line->column8, line->column9, line->column10);
}

// print tree
void print_tree(Node *root, int level)
{
  int i;

  if (root)
  {
    print_tree(root->right, level + 1);
    print_tree(root->left, level + 1);
    print_table(root->avl_info);
  }
}
```

And here is the code that matters:

```
Node *load_file_test(char filename[], Node *root)
{
  Avl_info csv[LINE_NUMBER]; 

  FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");


  char buff[LINE_NUMBER]; // n lines

  int row_count = 0;
  int field_count = 0;

  int i = 0;

  if (!fp)
  {
    printf("File is empty or do not exists.\n");
    exit;
  }
  else
  { // column

    while (fgets(buff, 1024, fp))
    {
      field_count = 0;
      row_count++;

      if (row_count == 1)
      {
        continue; // skip first line/column names
      }

      char *field = strtok(buff, ",");

      while (field)
      {
        if (field_count == 0)
          strcpy(csv[i].column1, field);

        if (field_count == 1)
          strcpy(csv[i].column2, field);

        if (field_count == 2)
          strcpy(csv[i].column3, field);

        if (field_count == 3)
          strcpy(csv[i].column4, field);

        if (field_count == 4)
          strcpy(csv[i].column5, field);

        if (field_count == 5)
          strcpy(csv[i].column6, field);

        if (field_count == 6)
          strcpy(csv[i].column7, field);

        if (field_count == 7)
          strcpy(csv[i].column8, field);

        if (field_count == 8)
          strcpy(csv[i].column9, field);

        if (field_count == 9)
          strcpy(csv[i].column10, field);

        field = strtok(NULL, ",");

        field_count++;
        csv[i].key_idx = i;
      }
      i++;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("Data loaded.\n\n");
  }

  Avl_info csv_aux[LINE_NUMBER];

  for (int i = 1; i <= LINE_NUMBER; i++)
  {
    csv_aux[i].key_idx = csv[i].key_idx;
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column1, csv[i].column1);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column2, csv[i].column2);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column3, csv[i].column3);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column4, csv[i].column4);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column5, csv[i].column5);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column6, csv[i].column6);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column7, csv[i].column7);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column8, csv[i].column8);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column9, csv[i].column9);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column10, csv[i].column10);

    printf("id: %d - iso_code: %s - continent: %s - location: %s - date: %s - total_cases: %s - new_cases: %s - new_cases_smoothed: %s - total_deaths: %s - new_deaths: %s - new_deaths_smoothed: %s -\n",
               csv_aux[i].key_idx, csv_aux[i].column1, csv_aux[i].column2, csv_aux[i].column3, csv_aux[i].column4, csv_aux[i].column5, csv_aux[i].column6, csv_aux[i].column7, csv_aux[i].column8, csv_aux[i].column9, csv_aux[i].column10);

    root = insert(root, csv_aux);
  }

  return root;
}


int main()
{
  int op, val;
  Node *root = NULL;
  Avl_info *data;
  char csv_name[20];

  printf("Inicio\n\n");

  do
  {
    printf("\n\n\t0 - Exit\n\t1 - Insert\n\t2 - Remove\n\t3 - Print\n\t4 - load csv\n\t\n\n");
    scanf("%d", &op);

    switch (op)
    {

    case 0:
      printf("Leaving...");
      break;

    case 1:
      data = malloc(sizeof(Avl_info));

      printf("id: ");
      scanf("%d", &data->key_idx);

      printf("\niso_code: ");
      scanf("%s", data->column1);

      printf("\ncontinent: ");
      scanf("%s", data->column2);

      printf("\nlocation: ");
      scanf("%s", data->column3);

      printf("\ndate: ");
      scanf("%s", data->column4);

      printf("\ntotal_cases: ");
      scanf("%s", data->column5);

      printf("\nnew_cases: ");
      scanf("%s", data->column6);

      printf("\nnew_cases_smoothed: ");
      scanf("%s", data->column7);

      printf("\ntotal_deaths: ");
      scanf("%s", data->column8);

      printf("\nnew_deaths: ");
      scanf("%s", data->column9);

      printf("\nnew_deaths_smoothed: ");
      scanf("%s", data->column10);

      root = insert(root, data);
      break;

    case 2:
      printf("Remove an element by id: ");
      scanf("%d", &val);
      root = remove_element(root, val);
      break;

    case 3:
      printf("| id | iso_code | continent | location | date | total_cases | new_cases | new_cases_smoothed | total_deaths | new_deaths | new_deaths_smoothed\n");
      print_tree(root, 1);
      break;

    case 4:
      // printf("csv name: ");
      // scanf("%s", csv_name);

      printf("Loading data...\n");
      root = load_file_test("csv_file.csv", root);

    default:
      printf("\nInvalid option.\n");
    }
  } while (op != 0);

  return 0;
}
```

The CSV structure:

```
iso_code,continent,location,date,total_cases,new_cases,new_cases_smoothed,total_deaths,new_deaths,new_deaths_smoothed
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-02-24,5.0,5.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,1
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-02-25,5.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-02-26,5.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-02-27,5.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0
AFG,Asia,Afghanistan,2020-02-28,5.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,2
```

When I compile the code and use the inputs (1-4), the options 1 to 3 goes well. The problem is when I use the 4 option. I in the `Node *load_file_test(char filename[], Node *root)` function close to the final, I create an csv_aux structure, so I can iterate it and assign the array of csv structure (Avl_info) to the csv_aux insert to the tree iteractively in the for loop.

```
...
Avl_info csv_aux[LINE_NUMBER];

  for (int i = 1; i <= LINE_NUMBER; i++)
  {
    csv_aux[i].key_idx = csv[i].key_idx;
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column1, csv[i].column1);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column2, csv[i].column2);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column3, csv[i].column3);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column4, csv[i].column4);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column5, csv[i].column5);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column6, csv[i].column6);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column7, csv[i].column7);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column8, csv[i].column8);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column9, csv[i].column9);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column10, csv[i].column10);

    printf("id: %d - iso_code: %s - continent: %s - location: %s - date: %s - total_cases: %s - new_cases: %s - new_cases_smoothed: %s - total_deaths: %s - new_deaths: %s - new_deaths_smoothed: %s -\n",
               csv_aux[i].key_idx, csv_aux[i].column1, csv_aux[i].column2, csv_aux[i].column3, csv_aux[i].column4, csv_aux[i].column5, csv_aux[i].column6, csv_aux[i].column7, csv_aux[i].column8, csv_aux[i].column9, csv_aux[i].column10);

    root = insert(root, csv_aux);
  }
...
```

I even print the results of csv_aux before insert it into the root to know if the right elements are being assigned correctly and here is the results:

[Code results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVqiW.png)

So, in the print the values were assigned correctly, but when I insert in the tree, it says that the tree already have an element (even it being garbage) and when I print the tree, it print an integer in 'id' property and garbage in the others:

[print_tree function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cc35.png)

Even I passing the root as a pointer or returning the root i have the exactly same results:

```
void load_file_test(char filename[], Node *root)
{
  Avl_info csv[LINE_NUMBER]; 

  FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");


...

  Avl_info csv_aux[LINE_NUMBER];

  for (int i = 1; i <= LINE_NUMBER; i++)
  {
    csv_aux[i].key_idx = csv[i].key_idx;
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column1, csv[i].column1);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column2, csv[i].column2);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column3, csv[i].column3);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column4, csv[i].column4);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column5, csv[i].column5);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column6, csv[i].column6);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column7, csv[i].column7);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column8, csv[i].column8);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column9, csv[i].column9);
    strcpy(csv_aux[i].column10, csv[i].column10);

    printf("id: %d - iso_code: %s - continent: %s - location: %s - date: %s - total_cases: %s - new_cases: %s - new_cases_smoothed: %s - total_deaths: %s - new_deaths: %s - new_deaths_smoothed: %s -\n",
               csv_aux[i].key_idx, csv_aux[i].column1, csv_aux[i].column2, csv_aux[i].column3, csv_aux[i].column4, csv_aux[i].column5, csv_aux[i].column6, csv_aux[i].column7, csv_aux[i].column8, csv_aux[i].column9, csv_aux[i].column10);

    root = insert(root, csv_aux);
  }

}

//Using in the main
int main(){
...

case 4:
      // printf("csv name: ");
      // scanf("%s", csv_name);

      printf("Loading data...\n");
      load_file_test("csv_file.csv", root);
...
```

Obs: The first int in struct is used to iterate and create o id column in the csv

```
typedef struct
{
  int key_idx;
  ...
```

I iterate here:

```
void load_file_test(char filename[], Node *root)
{
...
else
  { // column

    while (fgets(buff, 1024, fp))
    {
      field_count = 0;
      row_count++;

      if (row_count == 1)
      {
        continue; // skip first line/column names
      }

      char *field = strtok(buff, ",");

      while (field)
      {
        if (field_count == 0)
          strcpy(csv[i].column1, field);

        if (field_count == 1)
          strcpy(csv[i].column2, field);

        if (field_count == 2)
          strcpy(csv[i].column3, field);

        if (field_count == 3)
          strcpy(csv[i].column4, field);

        if (field_count == 4)
          strcpy(csv[i].column5, field);

        if (field_count == 5)
          strcpy(csv[i].column6, field);

        if (field_count == 6)
          strcpy(csv[i].column7, field);

        if (field_count == 7)
          strcpy(csv[i].column8, field);

        if (field_count == 8)
          strcpy(csv[i].column9, field);

        if (field_count == 9)
          strcpy(csv[i].column10, field);

        field = strtok(NULL, ",");

        field_count++;
        csv[i].key_idx = i;
      }
      i++;
    }
...
```

Can someone please help me? I'm really can't find out what is going on.

You can try use the 2, 3 and 3 options (insert and remove by id and print the tree in a table format) and you'll see that it works perfectly:

[Working tree pt1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ragq.png)

[Working tree pt2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giuIm.png)

[Working tree pt3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aF8I.png)

Comment: `char buff[LINE_NUMBER];` is only 5 characters long, but `fgets(buff, 1024, fp)` reads up to 1023 characters plus 1 null terminator into that buffer.

Comment: Also, if you use `char buff[1024];` remember to check that the null-terminated string in `buff` ends with a newline character (`'\n'`) after the `fgets` call, and strip it out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the advises! Could you please tell me how can I do that?

Comment: Assuming `fgets(buff, 1024, fp)` did not return `NULL`, then `len = strlen(buff);` `if (buff[len - 1] != '\n')` `{` `printf("Line too long\n");` `exit(1);` `}` `else` `{` `buff[len - 1] = '\0'; /* strip trailing newline */` `}`.

Comment: By the way, `exit;` in your code doesn't do anything.

Comment: I think that you understood something wrong or my logic might be incorrect.  LINE_NUMBER = number of rows, same for 1024. I should describe ```fgets``` as ```fgets(buff, LINE_NUMBER, fp)```. You probably understood that 1024/LINE_NUMBER is the lenght of a row

Comment: I understand that the code you posted has `#define LINE_NUMBER 5`, `char buff[LINE_NUMBER];` and `fgets(buff, 1024, fp);` which will clearly lead to *undefined behavior* if `fgets` reads a line longer than 4 characters including the newline character. The comment `// n lines` after `char buff[LINE_NUMBER];` suggests that *you* have misunderstood something basic.